# Struts2 - file selection field value disappears on validation error

Tags: file, validation, struts2

I have a typical struts2 form with a File selection field:

```
<s:form action="%{#parameters.myAction}" namespace="/" method="post" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" focusElement="storeBrandNameId">
 <s:textfield name="storeBrandName" id="storeBrandNameId" size="40" maxlength="50" required="true" key="storeBrandName-label" tooltip="%{getText('storeBrandName-label-help')}" />
 <s:file name="storeImage" key="storeImage-label"/>
 /* ... Other fields removed for clarity ... */
 <s:submit key="submit" />
</s:form>
```

The form works fine, except when I have a validation error (using XML validation). In that case, all the fields values are preserved except the selected file (if any).

Why is the selected file cleared on validation error? Is it a bug on my side? a struts2 limitation? or a typical browser limitation? Is there a way around?

Comment: It seems to be a browser limitation, but maybe there are alternate ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a file input field cannot be changed or initialized for security reason.

In your form, you have two fields, the text-field, and the file-field.
I don't think users will care if they loose the value of the input field when the file they selected was wrong. They will be annoyed only when the value in the text-field was wrong, and because of that they need to pick-up the file again.
So you could just do an ajax validation for the text-field value before submitting the form (or better, as they type the value!). If there is a problem, the form is not submitted, user fixes it and don't loose the file-field value.

Comment: I like the idea of pre-validation to avoid server-side errors. I simply added `validate="true"` to the `<s:form` to enable client-side validation. Thanks.

Comment: @Resh32 You must not rely solely on client-side validation since it may be bypassed trivially.

Comment: @Dave Newton I do not, but am I right assuming that `validate="true"` performs both client and server-side validation?

Comment: @Resh32 Seems easy enough to try. Note that not all validations are available on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

File fields may not be pre-filled; this is an HTML thing, for security purposes.

If a file was already uploaded, you could remember that and offer to use the just-uploaded file. I'd still show the file input box. This would (slightly) complicate validation.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a normal use-case and you need to handle this in order to preserve data and show the selected values to the user even on validation error.

Normally validation error let workflow interceptor to redirect back to the page and show the page with errors, which means your actual method never got called.

Struts2 provides a way to prepare any data you need for your action to work properly.User [Preparable](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/preparable-interface.html) interface and use its prepare method.

Its `prepare()` method get called before the validation and you can set any values required to show if there is any error.

In short `prepare()` method work as init method to do any such sort of work